# cmake: regular (SHARED) library depending on a header-only (INTERFACE) library

Tags: cmake, header-only, find-package

Include paths for header-only dependencies not propagating to non-header-only library targets.

cmake 3.25.3,  gcc 12.2.0.

1. I have a header-only library,  let's call it `foo`:

```
# foo CMakeLists.txt
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
```

`foo` exists to provide some c++ header files

```
# foo CMakeLists.txt 

target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)

install(
  TARGETS foo
  EXPORT fooTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Runtime
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Development
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib COMPONENT Runtime
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include COMPONENT Development
  BUNDLE DESTINATION bin COMPONENT Runtime)
```

2. `foo` generates+exports .cmake config files to drive `find_package`

```
# foo cmake/fooConfig.cmake.in
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/fooTargets.cmake")
check_required_components("@PROJECT_NAME@")
```

and

```
# foo CMakeLists.txt
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION 1.0
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion)
configure_package_config_file(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/fooConfig.cmake.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfigVersion.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/foo)
install(
  EXPORT fooTargets
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/foo)
install(
  FILES
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfigVersion.cmake"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fooConfig.cmake"
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/foo)
```

3. I have a shared library,  let's call it `bar`.
   `bar` is in a separate codebase

```
# bar CMakeLists.txt
find_package(foo CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(bar SHARED bar.cpp)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC 
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
```

4. `bar` needs `foo` headers to compile:

```
# bar CMakeLists.txt
target_link_libraries(bar INTERFACE foo)
```

5. **PROBLEM** compilation of `bar.cpp` doesn't receive `foo` headers:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 
g++ -Ipath/to/bar/include path/to/bar.cpp ...   # path/to/foo/include missing
```

This only happens for an INTERFACE dependency.
If I make foo a SHARED target + use it in bar as a PUBLIC dependency,  then foo headers
get forwarded to the compiler

6. (UGLY) WORKAROUND:  when depending on a header-only library,  add a hint:

```
# bar CMakeLists.txt

get_target_property(tmp foo INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set_property(
  TARGET bar
  APPEND PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${tmp})
```

QUESTIONS

Is this necessary?   Is there something wrong with my header-only packaging?
Some missing ingredient in fooConfig.cmake.in ?

Comment: `target_link_libraries(bar INTERFACE foo)` - That line means that you do NOT want properties of `foo` to be attached to the `bar`. Instead use `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC` linkage.

Comment: Thanks for reply!   I tried that,  but cmake doesn't seem to think that's appropriate.  cmake 3.25.3 gives this error:  `INTERFACE library can only be used with the INTERFACE keyword of target_link_libraries`

Comment: `bar` isn't an INTERFACE library, so calling `target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)` cannot cause such error.

Comment: Thanks,  got it.   The error I reported came from header-only library depending on another header-only library;    the error applies to the first argument of `target_link_libraries()`,  not the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

1. regular library `bar` depending on header-only library `foo`:

```
target_link_libraries(bar PUBLIC foo)
```

2. header-only library `quux` depending on header-only library `foo`:

```
target_link_libraries(quux INTERFACE foo)
```